# Phone gap iOS11 Display Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, phonegap

Have just downloaded the beta version of iOS 11 to test my application and the status bar (where the battery and clock is) is displaying grey rather than the background colour set in the body. Did not have the issue with my app on iOS 10.

Is anyone else having the same issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding the new `viewport-fit=cover` meta tag, you will also need to handle the fact that on the iPhone X the status bar is larger than 20px due to the notch for the camera and speaker.

You can handle this automatically in CSS using the new `safe-area-inset-*` constants in iOS 11.
i.e., `padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);`

If you're curious, I wrote a bit more about these changes and the new CSS constants: https://ayogo.com/blog/ios11-viewport/

Answer (score 0):

Answer!! Include this as your new meta tag!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **viewport-fit=cover** to your viewport meta tag will expand your site to fill the entire screen and not just the safe area.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
```

**safe-area-inset-***

**Note:** In order to handle any adjustment that may be required iOS 11's version of Safari includes some constants that can be used when **viewport-fit=cover** is being used.

padding: constant(safe-area-inset-left);
..
safe-area-inset-top
safe-area-inset-right
safe-area-inset-left
safe-area-inset-bottom